# Compile Android appwidget

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have 2 android projects in eclipse, one is the main application, the other one is a widget for the home screen. I'd like to open the main application when the user clicks the widget. However, when i create an Intent with an Activity from the main application, i get a "NoClassDefFoundError" during runtime.

The Widget compiles fine, as i've added the main application to the build path. Does anyone konw how i can compile an android widget so i can reference classes of the main app?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a `BroadcastReciever` in your Application that has the `Activity` you wish to launch and then just launch it from within that Applicaiton